# Pass object as offset in jQuery Sparkline

Tags: jquery, json, sparklines

The following code creates a Sparklines pie chart from a JSON string:

```
//Display Visitor Screen Size Stats

$.getJSON('models/ucp/traffic/traffic_display_bos.php',
{   
    type: 'ss',
    server: server,
    api: api,
    ip: ip,
},
function(data)
{
    //alert(data.screens);
    $('#traffic_bos_ss').sparkline(data.views,
    {
        type: "pie",
        height: "100%",
        tooltipFormat: "{{offset:offset}} - {{value}}",     
        tooltipValueLookups:
        {
            'offset': data.screens; 
        }
    });
});
```

The pie chart is successfully created, however, I'm having trouble with assigning the correct labels to the offset. The JSON string that is called is as follows:

```
{"screens":"{ 0: '1220x1080', 1: '1620x1080', 2: '1920x1080' }", "views":[2, 2, 61]}
```

I want it so that the **screens** of the JSON is inserted in the offset (data.screens). It should become:

```
tooltipValueLookups:
{
    'offset': { 0: '1220x1080', 1: '1620x1080', 2: '1920x1080' }    
}
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string:

```
{"screens":"{ 0: '1220x1080', 1: '1620x1080', 2: '1920x1080' }", "views":[2, 2, 61]}
```

is incorrect, as "screens" is a single string value (i.e. it has the value "{ 0: '1220x1080', 1: '1620x1080', 2: '1920x1080' }"). You want to remove the quotes so that it is an object with 3 value pairs ie.

```
{"screens": { "0": '1220x1080', "1": '1620x1080', "2": '1920x1080' }, "views":[2, 2, 61]}
```

See the following code which I've put in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/gLRG7/) for an example of this working:

```
var values = {"screens": { 0: '1220x1080', 1: '1620x1080', 2: '1920x1080' }, "views":[2, 2, 61]};

$('#test').sparkline(values.views,
                               {
                                   type: "pie",
                                   height: "100%",
                                   tooltipFormat: '{{offset:offset}}  - {{value}}',     
                                   tooltipValueLookups:
                                    {
                                        'offset': values.screens
                                    }
                               });
```

Comment: Glad I could help Bob.

Comment: I'm running into a problem again. So the above code works fine, but the JSON is now invalid. It is expecting a string instead of the 0, 1 and 2. Due to this, the getJSON does not work now. How do I make the JSON valid, yet make it also work with the offset?

Comment: I put the JSON I wrote through http://jsonlint.com/ an I could see it was invalid. I had incorrectly defined the objects; an object should use a string for the key, whereas I used an int. See the JSON documentation [here](http://www.json.org/). I've updated my answer and the jsFiddle.

Comment: No problems. It's good exercise for me too to validate my knowledge!